# Root node being set from seemingly nowhere in binary tree

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

When inserting a node into this binary tree(that doesn't accept duplicates) for whatever reason the root is not being set and even weirder is the fact that the root node seems to be set to whatever node is being entered. Here are the two files I'm using. I put a comment in capital letters in the tree.c to show where the weirdness is happening. Another thing to mention is that the trees with nodes that hold "integ" variable work as expected within the loop.

main.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXRELATIONS 10
#define MAXTUPLES 100
#define MAXCOLUMNS 15
#define MAXLEN 15
struct tree_node
{
    //string or integer
    char *sOrI;
    char *string;
    int integ;
    char *column;
    struct tree_node *left_child;
    struct tree_node *right_child;
};
struct column
{
    char name[MAXLEN+1];
    char SI[1];
    int bytez;
};
struct db
{
    int columnNo;
    struct column columns[MAXCOLUMNS];
    struct tree_node dataNodes[MAXCOLUMNS];
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *config;
    FILE *query;
    FILE *schema;
    FILE *dataFile;
    struct tree_node *current = NULL;
    int noOfRelations;
    int x,y;
    char relation[MAXLEN+1];
    struct db dbz[MAXLEN+1];
    int numOfColumns;
    if(argc==3){
        config = fopen(argv[1], "r+");
        query = fopen(argv[2], "r+");
        if(config==NULL){
            printf("Input file does not exist");
            return(1);
        }
        fscanf(config, "%d", &noOfRelations);
        for(x=0;fscanf(config, "%s", relation)!=EOF;x++){
            char dat[MAXLEN+1];
            char sch[MAXLEN+1];
            strcpy(dat, relation);
            strcpy(sch, relation);
            strcat(dat, ".dat");
            strcat(sch, ".sch");
            schema = fopen(sch, "r+");
            dataFile = fopen(dat, "rb");
            if(schema==NULL){
                printf("Couldn't find %s", sch);
                return(1);
            }
            if(dataFile==NULL){
                printf("Couldn't find %s", dat);
                return(1);
            }
            fscanf(schema, "%d", &numOfColumns);
            for(y=0;fscanf(schema, "%s%s%d", &(dbz[x].columns[y].name),&(dbz[x].columns[y].SI),&(dbz[x].columns[y].bytez))!=EOF;y++);
            if(strcmp(dbz[x].columns[0].SI,"S")==0){
                int t=0;
                while(1){
                    //printf("Hit!n");
                    char strHold[dbz[x].columns[0].bytez];
                    struct tree_node *start = NULL;
                    if(fread(&strHold, dbz[x].columns[0].bytez , 1, dataFile)==NULL){
                        break;
                    }
                    //printf("bytes %dn", dbz[x].columns[0].bytez);
                    printf("%sn", strHold);
                    current=NULL;
                    current = (struct tree_node *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree_node));
                    current->left_child = NULL;
                    current->right_child = NULL;
                    current->sOrI = dbz[x].columns[0].SI;
                    current->string = strHold;
                    current->column = dbz[x].columns[0].name;
                    start = &(dbz[x].dataNodes[0]);
                    insert(current, &(dbz[x].dataNodes[0]));
                    for(y=1;y<numOfColumns;y++){
                        if(strcmp(dbz[x].columns[y].SI,"S")==0){
                            current=NULL;
                            char strHold[dbz[x].columns[y].bytez];
                            //printf("bytes:%d y:%dn", dbz[x].columns[y].bytez,y);
                            fread(&strHold,dbz[x].columns[y].bytez , 1, dataFile);
                            printf("%sn", strHold);
                            current = (struct tree_node *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree_node));
                            current->left_child = NULL;
                            current->right_child = NULL;
                            current->sOrI = dbz[x].columns[y].SI;
                            current->string = strHold;
                            current->column = dbz[x].columns[y].name;
                            insert(current, &(dbz[x].dataNodes[y]));
                        }
                        else{
                            current=NULL;
                            int intHold;
                            //printf("bytes:%d y:%dn", dbz[x].columns[y].bytez,y);
                            fread(&intHold,dbz[x].columns[y].bytez , 1, dataFile);
                            printf("%dn", intHold);
                            current = (struct tree_node *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree_node));
                            current->left_child = NULL;
                            current->right_child = NULL;
                            current->sOrI = dbz[x].columns[y].SI;
                            current->integ = intHold;
                            current->column = dbz[x].columns[y].name;
                            insert(current, &(dbz[x].dataNodes[y]));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                int intHold;
                while(fread(&intHold,dbz[x].columns[0].bytez , 1, dataFile)!=NULL){
                    printf("%dn", intHold);
                    current = (struct tree_node *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree_node));
                    current->left_child = NULL;
                    current->right_child = NULL;
                    current->sOrI = dbz[x].columns[0].SI;
                    current->integ = intHold;
                    current->column = dbz[x].columns[0].name;
                    insert(current, &(dbz[x].dataNodes[0]));
                    for(y=1;y<numOfColumns;y++){
                        if(strcmp(dbz[x].columns[y].SI,"S")==0){
                            current=NULL;
                            char strHold[dbz[x].columns[y].bytez];
                            fread(&strHold,dbz[x].columns[y].bytez , 1, dataFile);
                            printf("%sn", strHold);
                            current = (struct tree_node *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree_node));
                            current->left_child = NULL;
                            current->right_child = NULL;
                            current->sOrI = dbz[x].columns[y].SI;
                            current->string = strHold;
                            current->column = dbz[x].columns[y].name;
                            insert(current, &(dbz[x].dataNodes[y]));
                        }
                        else{
                            int intHold;
                            fread(&intHold,dbz[x].columns[y].bytez , 1, dataFile);
                            printf("%dn", intHold);
                            current = (struct tree_node *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree_node));
                            current->left_child = NULL;
                            current->right_child = NULL;
                            current->sOrI = dbz[x].columns[y].SI;
                            current->integ = intHold;
                            current->column = dbz[x].columns[y].name;
                            insert(current, &(dbz[x].dataNodes[y]));
                        }
                    }
                    printf("nn");
                }
            }
            fclose(dataFile);
            fclose(schema);
            break;
        }
        fclose(config);
        return(0);
    }
    printf("Incorrect number of argumentsn");
    return(1);
}
```

tree.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLEN 15
struct tree_node
{
    //string or integer
    char *sOrI;
    char *string;
    int integ;
    char *column;
    struct tree_node *left_child;
    struct tree_node *right_child;
};
void insert(struct tree_node * node, struct tree_node ** start)
{
    printf("node type: %s node column: %sn", node->sOrI, node->column);
    if((*start)==NULL)
    {
        if(node->string){
            printf("node %s is setn",node->string);
        }
        *start = node;
        return;
    }
    if(strcmp(node->sOrI, "S")==0){
        printf("node string: %s, start string: %sn", node->string, (*start)->string);//WITHIN THE BIG LOOP THESE ARE IDENTICAL
        if(strcmp(node->string,(*start)->string)<0)
        {
            printf("Leftsn");
            insert(node, &(*start)->left_child);
        }
        else if(strcmp(node->string,(*start)->string)>0)
        {
            printf("Rightsn");
            insert(node, &(*start)->right_child);
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("node string: %d, start string: %dn", node->integ, (*start)->integ);
        if(node->integ<(*start)->integ)
        {
            printf("Leftin");
            insert(node, &(*start)->left_child);
        }
        else if(node->integ>(*start)->integ)
        {
            printf("Rightin");
            insert(node, &(*start)->right_child);
        }
    }
}
```

Now If I try and do something like

```html
current=NULL;                                       
current = (struct tree_node *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree_node));                 
current->left_child = NULL;
current->right_child = NULL; 
current->sOrI = "S";
current->string = "a";
current->column = "column"; 
insert(current, &(dbz[0].dataNodes[0]));

current=NULL;                                       
current = (struct tree_node *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree_node));                 
current->left_child = NULL;
current->right_child = NULL; 
current->sOrI = "S";
current->string = "b";
current->column = "column"; 
insert(current, &(dbz[0].dataNodes[0]));

current=NULL;                                       
current = (struct tree_node *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree_node));                 
current->left_child = NULL;
current->right_child = NULL; 
current->sOrI = "S";
current->string = "c";
current->column = "column"; 
insert(current, &(dbz[0].dataNodes[0]));
```

I get the expected output so I know that the binary tree and everything works as expected, the problem must be within the big crazy loop. I've isolated every part of my code that might be broken and everything seems to work as expected. I don't need advice on best practices unless it will affect the result of this program, just looking for a pair of fresh eyes to point out what is causing the problem at hand. Thank you for your time!

Output of one run with one data file/schema file

`Smith,Robert
node type: S node column: Name
node Smith,Robert is set
PSY
node type: S node column: Major
node PSY is set
CSI
node type: S node column: Minor
node CSI is set
57
node type: I node column: Totcr
39
node type: I node column: Majcr
Woods,Jane
node type: S node column: Name
node string: Woods,Jane, start string: Woods,Jane
CSI
node type: S node column: Major
node string: CSI, start string: CSI
BUS
node type: S node column: Minor
node string: BUS, start string: BUS
97
node type: I node column: Totcr
node string: 97, start string: 57
Righti
node type: I node column: Totcr
68
node type: I node column: Majcr
node string: 68, start string: 39
Righti
node type: I node column: Majcr
Ramsey,Elaine
node type: S node column: Name
node string: Ramsey,Elaine, start string: Ramsey,Elaine
BUS
node type: S node column: Major
node string: BUS, start string: BUS
PSY
node type: S node column: Minor
node string: PSY, start string: PSY
107
node type: I node column: Totcr
node string: 107, start string: 57
Righti
node type: I node column: Totcr
node string: 107, start string: 97
Righti
node type: I node column: Totcr
88
node type: I node column: Majcr
node string: 88, start string: 39
Righti
node type: I node column: Majcr
node string: 88, start string: 68
Righti
node type: I node column: Majcr
Wharton,Tom
node type: S node column: Name
node string: Wharton,Tom, start string: Wharton,Tom
BUS
node type: S node column: Major
node string: BUS, start string: BUS
PSY
node type: S node column: Minor
node string: PSY, start string: PSY
117
node type: I node column: Totcr
node string: 117, start string: 57
Righti
node type: I node column: Totcr
node string: 117, start string: 97
Righti
node type: I node column: Totcr
node string: 117, start string: 107
Righti
node type: I node column: Totcr
98
node type: I node column: Majcr
node string: 98, start string: 39
Righti
node type: I node column: Majcr
node string: 98, start string: 68
Righti
node type: I node column: Majcr
node string: 98, start string: 88
Righti
node type: I node column: Majcr
Baker,Norma
node type: S node column: Name
node string: Baker,Norma, start string: Baker,Norma
BIO
node type: S node column: Major
node string: BIO, start string: BIO
CSI
node type: S node column: Minor
node string: CSI, start string: CSI
39
node type: I node column: Totcr
node string: 39, start string: 57
Lefti
node type: I node column: Totcr
25
node type: I node column: Majcr
node string: 25, start string: 39
Lefti
node type: I node column: Majcr`

Comment: Can you please clarify your post? It is confusing. In the same sentence you seemingly make contradicting statements. That the root node is set and the root node is not set.: "for whatever reason the root is not being set and even weirder is the fact that the root node seems to be set "

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't think of a good way to explain this, it doesn't make much sense to me either. What I meant was that it seemingly isn't being set by the first node that is supposed to be inserted into the tree. After the first node is "inserted" every node that is inserted after seems to think that the "start" node is the same as the "current" node. I added a sample output to better clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the key for your nodes is being declared locally.

```
char strHold[dbz[x].columns[y].bytez];
```

The above appears to be your key. You can store a pointer to that key in your node to be inserted, but when you leave the frame in which strHold is declared, you have lost your reference to it. Your other example works because the key strings are stored in static memory. I would guess that it appears the most recent key is in root because the root key pointer is still pointing to strHold in that frame, and you're constantly overwriting it with the new key. Declare dynamic memory to store your keys so they persist.

**edit**:
Looking at your node structure, string is just a pointer to a character. You need to actually allocate storage that will stick around as long as you want the node to exist.

```
struct tree_node
{
    //string or integer
    char *sOrI;
    char *string;
    int integ;
    char *column;
    struct tree_node *left_child;
    struct tree_node *right_child;
};
```

...

node->string points to strHold, and *start->string likely does too.

```
if(strcmp(node->string,(*start)->string)<0)
```

main.c:

Here's how you declare string hold, it's a local variable, which means that the memory for it exists on the stack. Once the frame has exited, you don't own that memory anymore ( however, the memory still *may* be set to what you stored there before you exited the frame - but that doesn't mean it's okay to use. )

```
char strHold[dbz[x].columns[y].bytez];
```

You then load your newly created node's string field with a reference to strHold, which as discussed above, is in memory local to the current frame.

```
current->string = strHold;
```

This means that when you exit the frame, you're likely not going to be pointing to a memory location that stores the string you just tried to enter for very long. Also, since all the nodes that you're entering in this loop have pointers to that variable, they all would appear to have the last value you copied into strHold  in the node->string pointer.

The example you provided that works, works because the strings you're assigning to `node->string` have unique memory locations, and are persisted throughout the lifetime of your program in read only memory.

That's what you need to do, only you need to do it dynamically. In the same way that you allocated your node using malloc, you'll need to allocate space for your string using malloc.

So instead of:

```
node->string = strHold;
```

You'll probably want something more like:

```
node->string = malloc( sizeof(char) * strlen(strHold) )
//if malloc didn't fail...
strcpy(node->string, strHold)
```

The difference being that now, your node's string field points to a region of memory that exclusively belongs to that node, and is storing what was in the contents of strHold. Don't forget to free it when you're cleaning up!

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the answer but I only want strHold to be declared locally, it SHOULD be overwritten with the new strHold, not persisted. The thing I need to persist is the root node of dbz[x].dataNodes[y] and all of it's children. strHold is supposed to be allocated the size of dbz[x].columns[y].bytez . I attempted to use dynamic allocation like you suggested but I get a seg fault immediately.

Comment: I declared `char *strHold` at the top and instead of `char strHold[dbz[x].columns[y].bytez];` I tried to use `strHold = (char*)realloc(strHold, dbz[x].columns[y].bytez);`

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear - I'll update my answer. I was trying to say that the `char * string` field in your node structure is only a pointer, and you need the character array (string) its pointing to to persist. What you were doing is pointing node->string to strHold, which you'd then overwrite each time you inserted a node. You need to declare storage space for node->string, then copy the key (possible from strHold) into node->string. Also, note that realloc on a non-null, non-malloc-family returned pointer causes errors.

Comment: any suggestions on how to go about that? Are you saying to not have the string field in my node structure be a pointer? I'm clearly very new at C.

Comment: No, check my edit and see if it helps. It's fine that it's a pointer, but just understand what that means. It simply _points_ to memory, it doesn't automatically allocate it.